# AllowOverride for userdir

Tags: php, apache-http-server, lamp, htaccess

I need to allow all `userdir` (`host.com/~user`) to override options in their `.htaccess`, such as `php_value`. Where do I configure Apache to `AllowOverride` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [cannot set it inside <Location> or similar blocks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride). So you must work around it. In my default config the following is used, this seems to be a useful way of doing it (of course you need to adapt the path if you change the UserDir path, too)

```
<Directory /home/*/public_html>
    AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be in /etc/httpd.conf, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your setup. In order for the latest Debian/Apache2 to access http:// host /~user, the "userdir" module must be enabled. You will need to edit this module's configuration file to configure AllowOverride:

```
vi /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf
```

Apache will need restarted after this update:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```